# How to make Mysql descriptor as global?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have method, that does conenct to MYSQL:

```
def connectDB():
    db = {
        'user': 'root',
        'password': '',
        'database': 'g'
    }

    """ Connect to MySQL database """
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                       database=db['database'],
                                       user=db['user'],
                                       password=db['password'])
        if conn.is_connected():

            print('Connected to MySQL database')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM apps_local")

            result = cur.fetchall()

            for record in result:
                url.append(record[11])

    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        print("Closed MySQL")
```

Another methods inserts data to Mysql:

```
def insert():
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO...")
  cur.commit()
```

Problem is that I method `insert()` does not work, because `cur` is not defined.

How can I make descriptor `cur` as global, that to do  queries in others methods?